# How to update shiny data frame in real time using checkboxes?

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following app below, it takes a dataframe which is created in the shiny server, and uses this to generate tab Panels, which in turn checkboxes within each tab panel (3 checkboxes per tab panel) - within each tab panel there is a "select all" box which is supposed to essentially check all of the boxes in that tab panel

So what i need help with - is that i would like it so that if i am on tab 1 and "press" the "select all" button, then it will "check" all those boxes in that tab Panel (and of course "un-pressing" that button will deselect those boxes) - But i would also want the functionality, so that if you select a number of checkboxes in different tabs, then it would update accordingly and will not lose any information, (this includes pressing select all on different tabs also)

So for example i would want the following behaviour:

If you select the "Edibles" Tab > then press "select all" - all 3 checkboxes are selected

Now if you then select the "Fried" tab > then press "cheese" which is one of the options for the individual checkboxes - you will now have in total 4 checkboxes selected, all those from the "edibles" tab and just the one from the "fried" tab

So if we now de-select the "select all" button from the first tab "edibles", it loses all information and the checkbox in "Fried" which was "cheese" no longer is checked,

**This is not the behaviour i would want - i would like it to update accordingly and have "cheese" still selected as we have unpressed select all**

I have printed off the names of what is being selected where and when on the actual app

code is below:

Any thoughts?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel")

  ), 
  tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
         tabPanel("Visualisation", 
                  width = 12, 
                  height = 800
         )


  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Price = c(1:15), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive"che



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      food <- unique(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food))
      food_panel <- lapply(seq_along(food), function(i) {
        ### filter the data only once
        food_dt <- dplyr::filter(nodes_data_reactive(), Food == food[i])

        ### Use the id, not the price, as the id is unique
        food_ids <- as.character(food_dt$id)
        selected_ids <- food_ids[food_ids %in% isolate({chosen_food()})] ### use isolate, so as to not be reactive to it

        tabPanel(food[i],
                 checkboxGroupInput(
                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i),
                   label = "Random Stuff",
                   choiceNames = as.character(food_dt$Product_name), ### for some reason it likes characters, not factors with extra levels
                   choiceValues = food_ids,
                   selected = selected_ids
                 ),
                 checkboxInput(
                   paste0("all_", i),
                   "Select all",
                   value = all(food_ids %in% isolate({chosen_food()}))
                 )
        )
      })











      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id = 't', food_panel)),
          "Items: ", renderText(paste0(chosen_food(), collapse = ", ")),
          "Names: ", renderText(paste0(chosen_food_names(), collapse = ", ")) 


      ) # end of Tab box


    }   

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {

      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE) %>%
        as.character()

      product_prices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Price) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choiceNames = product_choices,
                                   choiceValues = product_prices,
                                   selected = product_prices)
        } else {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choiceNames = product_choices,
                                   choiceValues = product_prices,
                                   selected = c()
          )
        }
      }

    })

  })

  chosen_food <- reactive({
    unlist(lapply(seq_along(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      # retrieve checkboxfood_NUMBER value
      input[[paste0("checkboxfood_", i)]]
    }))
  })
  chosen_food_names <- reactive({
    # turn selected chosen food values into names
    nodes_data_reactive()$Product_name[as.numeric(chosen_food())]
  })











} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were updating all checkbox groups that **didn't** have the *select all* option selected. The solution is to add an if condition that checks to see if all the options are selected or not by comparing the length of `input[[paste0("checkboxfood_", i)]]` with length of `product_choices`

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

#################################################
#################### UI.R #######################
#################################################

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel")

  ), 
  tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
         tabPanel("Visualisation", 
                  width = 12, 
                  height = 800
         )


  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")

#################################################
################## Server.R #####################
#################################################

server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Price = c(1:15), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive"che



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    #Select Food
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      food <- unique(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food))
      food_panel <- lapply(seq_along(food), function(i) {
        ### filter the data only once
        food_dt <- dplyr::filter(nodes_data_reactive(), Food == food[i])

        ### Use the id, not the price, as the id is unique
        food_ids <- as.character(food_dt$id)
        selected_ids <- food_ids[food_ids %in% isolate({chosen_food()})] ### use isolate, so as to not be reactive to it

        tabPanel(food[i],
                 checkboxGroupInput(
                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i),
                   label = "Random Stuff",
                   choiceNames = as.character(food_dt$Product_name), ### for some reason it likes characters, not factors with extra levels
                   choiceValues = food_ids,
                   selected = selected_ids
                 ),
                 checkboxInput(
                   paste0("all_", i),
                   "Select all",
                   value = all(food_ids %in% isolate({chosen_food()}))
                 )
        )
      })

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id = 't', food_panel)),
          "Items: ", renderText(paste0(chosen_food(), collapse = ", ")),
          "Names: ", renderText(paste0(chosen_food_names(), collapse = ", ")) 


      ) # end of Tab box


    }   

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {

      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE) %>%
        as.character()

      product_prices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Price) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choiceNames = product_choices,
                                   choiceValues = product_prices,
                                   selected = product_prices)
        } else {
          if((input[[paste0("all_", i)]] != TRUE) & (length(input[[paste0("checkboxfood_", i)]]) == length(product_choices)))
          {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                     paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                     label = NULL, 
                                     choiceNames = product_choices,
                                     choiceValues = product_prices,
                                     selected = c()
            )
          }}
      }

    })

  })

  chosen_food <- reactive({
    unlist(lapply(seq_along(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      # retrieve checkboxfood_NUMBER value
      input[[paste0("checkboxfood_", i)]]
    }))
  })
  chosen_food_names <- reactive({
    # turn selected chosen food values into names
    nodes_data_reactive()$Product_name[as.numeric(chosen_food())]
  })
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks for the help - there is now a problem in that if you try and select 3 checkboxes in one tab - then it flashes and does not work - it only works if you press "select all" to get all of those 3 checkboxes marked - is there a way to fix this? i would like it so that you can press 3 checkboxes and then the select all button will update accordinldnly - please advise!

Comment: Also the select all button worked previously in "deselecting" all of the checkboxes - now it does not work - if you unselect 1 of 3 checkboxes then press "select all" it should "deselect" all boxes, however it does - any advice for this too?